# #1314 - LOCK is not allowed in stored procedures

Tags: mysql

I have TB_EVENT_LOG table which is in production, I need to transfer that prod data into dummy table on same server and truncate the production table .In the mean time i want to lock the production table.
I am new to db, can anyone suggest efficient way to do the same.

```
CREATE event transfer_data
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 12 hour
STARTS  CURRENT TIME_STAMP
DO
BEGIN

LOCK TABLE TB_EVENT_LOG WRITE;
INSERT INTO TB_EVENT_LOG_dummy SELECT * FROM TB_EVENT_LOG ;
UNLOCK TABLES;
TRUNCATE TABLE TB_EVENT_LOG;


END |
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: What operating systems? Table engines? And are there anny programming languages available like PHP, Perl or Python?

Comment: i think you mean ubuntu.. then it should be possible to make a cronjob ( https://www.google.com/search?q=cronjob+every+12+hour ) and execute mysql queries with mysql program from the terminal.. something like `mysql -u user -p password < script.sql`  place `LOCK TABLE TB_EVENT_LOG WRITE;
INSERT INTO TB_EVENT_LOG_dummy SELECT * FROM TB_EVENT_LOG ;
UNLOCK TABLES;
TRUNCATE TABLE TB_EVENT_LOG;` in a .sql file

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that only copied records are deleted from the production table, transactions can be used instead of table locking.

E.g.

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO TB_EVENT_LOG_dummy SELECT * FROM TB_EVENT_LOG ;
TRUNCATE TABLE TB_EVENT_LOG;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: while copying if there is any transaction(means insert/update) happened on production is it causes any problem?

Comment: `START TRANSACTION READ ONLY` should work the same as a `LOCK TABLE` statement by the way. " The transaction access mode may be specified with SET TRANSACTION. ....
If the transaction access mode is set to READ ONLY, changes to tables are prohibited. This may enable storage engines to make performance improvements that are possible when writes are not permitted.  "  source https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-transaction.html  @Manikanta

Comment: @Manikanta  Inserts/updates done outside the transaction while the transaction is active will not be affected by the actions within the transaction.